# Yahoo gemini Get job status

Tags: yahoo-api

Im following this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/custom-reporting.html)

i have successfully got this result:

```
{
"errors": null,
"response": {
"jobId": "628cf1c0cd1c5d8a6c1765f618b7a0be34c50bc1564618",
"status": "submitted",
"jobResponse": null
}
}
```

ant tried GET call to check the status of the job , exactly as they are asking

https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/reports/custom/628cf1c0cd1c5d8a6c1765f618b7a0be34c50bc1564618?access_token=&advertiserId=21

but i get an error massage :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-
Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="unable_to_determine_oauth_type", realm="yahooapis.com"
```

what am i doing wrong ?
i have even tried adding the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo API wasn't that precise beside the fact they had some system maintenance

this is how the url for testing if job has finished:

```
String urlToCheckIfDownloadReady = "https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/reports/custom/" + jobId + "?access_token=" + refreshToken + "&advertiserId=" + config.mccCustomerId;

if status = completed
```

Get from the Json response the jobResponse and than download it